# What does this recursive algorithm do?

Tags: algorithm

I have an algorithm :

```
def generate (last, cur):
   if (cur>100):
      print cur
   return generate(cur, last+cur)
```

I have two questions:

- What will this function print?
- And, how to modify this function, so that it prints original output but in reverse order?

Comment: you did not try what it  prints ?

Comment: Maybe you want to elaborate a bit further. Have you actually tried to execute the algorithm?

Comment: If the code you show is Python code, please remember to indent it properly. Depending on indentation the code can do different things. Also add the Python language tag.

Comment: I have no laptop with me, just help me with solution please, not with clever words

Comment: The problem is that without proper indentation then the code you show could literally behave in three or four different ways. If you want us to be able to help you in any way we need to know the proper code.

Comment: Guys, faster please

Comment: This is given code, nothing more

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function `generate()` is called with parameters `1,1`, it prints the fibonacci series starting with the first value exceeding `100`, that is `144`

**Output:**

```
144
233
377
610
987
1597
.... till maximum stack depth is reached..
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this prints fibonacci series.

Comment: For values greater than 100.